# Detecting Rotation Direction of text with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

Problem Description: I have a Python script using OpenCV to determine the direction of rotation in an image. The goal is to identify whether the image is upside-down or not. I've provided my code below and would like suggestions for improvements or alternative approaches to achieve more accurate results.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("3_d.png")

# Convert to grayscale and invert
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

# Threshold the image
thres = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find coordinates of non-zero pixels
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thres > 0))

# Determine the angle of rotation
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]

# Adjust the angle to be within [-45, 45] degrees
if angle > 45:
    angle = -(angle - 90)
else:
    angle = -angle

# Define a threshold angle to determine rotation direction
threshold_angle = 90

# Check if the image is upside-down or not
if abs(angle - 180) < threshold_angle:
    print("Upside-Down Image")
else:
    print("Non-Inverted Image")
```

Expected Output: I expect the code to determine whether the input image is upside-down or
not based on the detected rotation angle.

Specific Questions:

1. Are there more accurate methods to determine the direction of rotation in an image?
2. Are there any optimizations or improvements that can be made to this code?

[This is the input image in which i would like to know how can i know that this image has to be rotated counter clockwise but i don't know how can do that using the code given above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xy2V.png)

[This is the expected output but i got totally upside down as my output what changes can i do in my code that can detect the type of rotation we have to perform in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqFSW.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You will need something else besides the angle from minAreaRect to know if the image is upside down. I think you have to look at whether the text is above or below the long lines that are properly above (?) your text